# WSL doesn't seem to connect to network at all

Tags: networking, updates, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ping

**System details:**

- Windows 11 Pro
- Official ISO image from Microsoft's website + Christitus WinUtil to create a custom image (used to remove bloatware)

Problem details, to summarize the problem here are commands and their respective responses in the terminal:

- `ping google.com`:

```
    Temporary failure in name resolution
```

- `ping 1.1.1.1`:

```
ping: connect: Network is unreachable
```

- `sudo apt update`:

```
Ign:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Ign:3 (link for Ubuntu archive) jammy-updates InRelease
Ign:4 (link for Ubuntu archive) jammy-backports InRelease
Err:2 (link for Ubuntu archive) jammy InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving '(link for Ubuntu archive)'
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 (link for Ubuntu archive) jammy-updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving '(link for Ubuntu archive)'
Err:4 (link for Ubuntu archive) jammy-backports InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving '(link for Ubuntu archive)'
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'security.ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

**What I have tried:**

- changed `/etc/resolv.conf` and `/etc/wsl.conf`
- made `etc/resolv.conf` immutable
- reset network settings
- unregistered Ubuntu and disabled **Hyper-V**, **Virtual Machine Platform** and **WSL** multiple times (rebooted after every single disable and enable)

**Results:** None, nothing worked, nothing fixed the problem

**Edit 1**: The Ubuntu distribution version I using is 22.04 LTS

and I think I found the origin of the problem, at least for now.
In my network adapters Hyper-V didn't create a virtual switch that will allow wsl to access my other network adapters through it, so the problem lies there I think... I tried to create a virtual switch using Hyper-V manager, but so far no success yet...

**Edit 2:** After uninstalling and reinstalling multiple times, neither WSL nor Ubuntu seem to properly install anymore apparently, as far as I understand.

This is the output of the function `wsl --version` as of my current situation:

```
WSL version: 2.1.5.0
Kernel version: 5.15.146.1-2
WSLg version: 1.0.60
MSRDC version: 1.2.5105
Direct3D version: 1.611.1-81528511
DXCore version: 10.0.25131.1002-220531-1700.rs-onecore-base2-hyp
Windows version: 10.0.22631.3235
```

When trying to launch ubuntu now this is what I get:

```
Launching Ubuntu...
Installing, this may take a few minutes...
WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x80070002
Error: 0x80070002 The system cannot find the file specified.

Press any key to continue...
```

I have tried to download the update manually from Microsoft's website: [https://wslstorestorage.blob.core.windows.net/wslblob/wsl_update_x64.msi\](https://wslstorestorage.blob.core.windows.net/wslblob/wsl_update_x64.msi%5C)
but in vain... now I can't even install Ubuntu anymore, and yes the same happens when I try to download other specific versions of the Ubuntu distro such as 22.04, 20.04, etc...

**Note:**

Well, however right before breaking it so it doesn't want to install anymore this time, I reckon that I got my first problem because there was no virtual switch adapter to allow wsl and distros to connect to the network I am using.
Typically the name for this adapter is vEthernet, and is managed by hyper-v. I tried to create one manually through hyper-v manager, but, in vain...

Comment: @SorenA The user is running Ubuntu on WSL on Windows, and the Ubuntu distribution is an official Canonical product and on-topic here.  Many questions might be *better* placed on Super User, but in most cases they are allowed here.  It's just not possible (in many cases) to expect users to be able to diagnose *where* the issue is occurring.  Sometimes we find that the problem needs an understanding of Ubuntu, sometimes Windows, and often both.

Comment: Akaidi - Can you [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1507109/edit) your question to include (a) your Ubuntu release, (b) the results from `wsl.exe --version`, (c) results of `ping "$(hostname).local"` in Bash?

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds I have updated the thread, I'll keep updating it every time I make a little progress. Thank you all for the help, really appreciate it

Comment: Given your current status, I might suggest [completely uninstalling and reinstalling](https://superuser.com/a/1755410/1210833).

Comment: I'm somewhat worried about the use of the Chris Titus tools here, in that something critical might be disabled, but I don't want to blame that without any evidence, of course.  I'd rather keep troubleshoot and hoping we can get you to a resolution.

Comment: Hmm - *"unregistered Ubuntu and disabled Hyper-V **Virtual Machine Platform" and "WSL" multiple times (rebooted after every single disable and enable)"* - It seems you have already attempted completely uninstalling/reinstalling :-/

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds yes same thing, i also suspected the Chris Titus winutil use, however I also got no proof whatsoever, just to be safe tho, I opened an issue on the github project repo (it's open source in case you never used it) asking them to provide a proper uninstaller for some feature, here is the link if you want to see "https://github.com/ChrisTitusTech/winutil/issues/1694"

Comment: Good idea - That was definitely on my list of things to suggest if we got to the point where we had any inclination it was the culprit, but I'm glad you went ahead and opened the issue.  As you clearly know, Chris does have experience with WSL, and even includes options in the installer for it and HyperV, so perhaps he has some thoughts on potential causes. I've subscribed to the GH issue as well, just in case ...

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds yeah i know, and agree, same thought process and reasons, hope he will manage something out